# Favourites not appearing in Internet explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, bookmarks, internet-explorer-11

I have reinstalled a machine and I copied the local user desktop and favourites as usual, when I tried to test see if the favourites were copied across properly, they didn't appear the favourites bar (which is supposed to have a white box in the centre where it lists the favourites) looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand why it keeps doing this I have tried using the file name "Favorites" and "Favourites" to appeal to any Language changes, but the same thing happened, IE 11 has been reset to default configuration and settings, the user is set as a local administrator and all the favourites have been copied into and replaced the old Favorites file in the users profile on the C drive.

what may be of interest is that they did appear when a USB drive was inserted with the favourites saved there but as soon as this was removed the favourites tab appears as is above.

How can I get the Favourites to display?

Comment: In your IE,go to Organize Favourites (In the Add to favourites menu) and see if they are listed there or no. If not simply drag them in it.

Comment: @Scorpion99 the window will not even appear to allow me to organise the favourites clicking Organise Favourites button does nothing :/

Comment: go to run and try the following : C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Favorites , are you able to see them there?

Comment: @Scorpion99 yes they are visible in that directory on the C: drive

Comment: IE11 should show these in the Favorites list

Comment: @Scorpion99 well it hasn't that's my problem

Comment: @Scorpion99 My user also reports that he is unable to add new favourites as well

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/902258/ie11-unable-to-add-website-to-favorites):

In my case I had errors in the registry for the "`Favorites`" keys in these locations:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell folders
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
```

Fixing these and restarting IE fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the Favorites folder under C:\users\username\Favorites..... verify that the files are not "Hidden". Just has a user where her Favorites was not appearing in IE. Went to look back at the Favorites folder and noticed that the icons were faded. Had my colleague go into the properties of one of the files that appeared hidden and sure enough.... it was marked as hidden. Selected all of the files and right-click--> Properties--> General tab and deselected "Hidden". Closed and re-opened IE and all of the Favorites appeared.