# IE11 - Unable to add website to Favorites

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Whenever I try to add any site to favourites (by dragging it to favorites bar/Alt-Z/Ctrl+D/clicking in UI) nothing happens.

The Favorites dir in my %userprofile% exists, is writeable, and has items.

Interestingly though the All Users equivalent seems broken:

```
C:\Users\All Users>mkdir Favorites
A subdirectory or file Favorites already exists.

C:\Users\All Users>cd Favorites
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm testing with IE 11.0.09600.
I've tried resetting user settings. (inetcpl.cpl -> Advanced -> Reset)

Comment: If I may, which version of Windows were you utilizing throughout this scenario?

Comment: @Run5k Blimey. 2 years ago. Hmm. Probably Windows 7.

Comment: Probably so… I was just wondering based upon the `C:\Users\All Users` reference point.  Regardless, can you potentially do us a favor and flag your own answer as the officially accepted solution?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [this article](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/31564.aspx).

Somehow my registry had entries that were mapping the Favourites folder to a disk that did not exist.

By correcting the "`Favorites`" keys in these locations and restarting IE the problem was resolved:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell folders
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
```